# Machine Learning for user modelling

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

I have a dataset where each row is a interaction of a user with a content.
I have user's features to represent the user (each user is uniquely represented through user.id):

`user.id, user.nationality, user.company, user.role`

and content's feature:

```
content.id, content.type, content.activity..
```

My goal is to use ML techniques to predict a content (given by a user.id).
My main problem is that, for a new prediction, I have the features of the user, but I do not have the features of the new content.

Comment: Do you have training data, i.e. pairs of `user.id` and `content.id` that go together?

Comment: @BrunoGL yes! i have

Comment: @gdlzzzz I wouldn't include contentid (or userid) as features. Are you basically doing a recommender based on Content Filtering? In that case you pass the new content features against each user feature set to see which users have a high chance of interacting with it.

Comment: @gdlzzzz is 1) your set of `contents` fixed, so given a new `user`, you want to choose which content from the existing pool of contents would be best for him. Or 2) for every new `user`, you create a completely new `content` just for him?

Comment: @BrunoGL 1) my contents is fixed.

Comment: @gdlzzzz did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a [classification problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification). Given a `user` and their `features`, pick the best `content` for him.

There are many classifiers that are for this task. I would say that your main problem is that most of your features are categorical and not numerical.

## Data preparation

With Sklearn for example, you can use `LabelEncoder` to transform categorical to numerical.

Below is an example of how to do this. You generate `X`, which is your features matrix. Each row is a `user` and the columns are the `features`.

Here are some dummy `users` I created. You data structure might be different, so you can try to make it like this, or do some more work on it.

```
users = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'nationality': 'american',
        'company': 'xyz',
        'role': 'ceo',
        'content.id': 1001
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'nationality': 'american',
        'company': 'abc',
        'role': 'cto',
        'content.id': 1002
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'nationality': 'canadian',
        'company': 'fgh',
        'role': 'cto',
        'content.id': 1001
    }
]
```

Now, you can encode your categories. This means that for every *word* in your data, you assign a number to it. The `LabelEncoder` can do this for you. With this, you generate `X`, which is your feature matrix, where every row represents a `user`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

nationality_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit([user['nationality'] for user in users])
company_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit([user['company'] for user in users])
role_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit([user['role'] for user in users])

X = []
for user in users:
    X.append([
        nationality_encoder.transform([user['nationality']])[0],
        company_encoder.transform([user['company']])[0],
        role_encoder.transform([user['role']])[0]
    ])
print(X)
>> [[0, 2, 0], 
>>  [0, 0, 1],
>>  [1, 1, 1]]
```

Then you can generate `y`, which are your labels. The `content.id` of each user. Here I assume you have the `user`-`content` pairs like you said you did. This vector has the same length as `X`. Each row of `X` is associate to the ordered values in `y`. So the `user` in `X[2]` has the `content.id` in `y[2]`.

```
y = [user['content.id'] for user in users]
print(y)
>> [1001, 1002, 1001]
```

## Classifier

Now you have your `X` and `y`, your features and labels.

Not all classifier will perform well with categorical data, but I would suggest you start with a `DecisionTreeClassifier`.

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
decision_tree.fit(X, y)
```

## New predictions

Now that you have a trained tree, you can predict the `content.id` for `users` that do not have it.

Suppose you have this new user:

```
new_user = {
        'id': 999,
        'nationality': 'american',
        'company': 'fgh',
        'role': 'ceo'
    }
```

You can apply the same transformation to get the `X` for him. However, now you do not know `y`, which is what you are trying to find out.

```
new_user_X = [[
    nationality_encoder.transform([new_user['nationality']])[0],
    company_encoder.transform([new_user['company']])[0],
    role_encoder.transform([new_user['role']])[0]
]]
```

Use the `decision_tree` you created to make a prediction. In this dummy example, the `new_user` should have `content.id == 1`.

```
new_user_content = decision_tree.predict(new_user_X)
print(new_user_content)
>> [1]
```