# 250 Categorical values

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, dataset, categorical-data

I have a dataset which has only categorical values. As I came across a few articles people suggested that **KNN** / **Random forest** would work for *dataset* like this. Though in R it couldn't handle as if contains more than 53 categories.

Whereas in Sklearn, I used  linear regression against each column to the column which I was predicting. After which I created a weighted average of all the outputs. But I'm pretty sure it's not the right way.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

PS : The *dataset* contains **4 columns**  with only categorical values. With 200 - 250 different categories in each column.

Comment: did you try using http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html or http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html ?

Comment: you can have a look at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/35646/54395 for some categorical data usage with SKlearn

Comment: I saw the post. Will it be any good for a dataset with 4 columns with categorical values. Where each one has 200 - 250 range of categorical data

Comment: it will work (i.e. run). If it will be any good is up to you. That is the beauty of Data Science: you get to experiment to find out.

Comment: Take a look [at different ways to handle categorical variables](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/beyond-one-hot-exploration-categorical-variables.html). Also, it is important to know how the values of each individual categorical variable is distributed. This is relevant e.g. for regression where the rare values will only marginally contribute to the error term and thus the model will fit to highly frequent values (to reduce the error). There are ways to combat that. Would you mind to provide an excerpt, obscured, or artificial data? It will help you question.

Comment: Is there any mapping you could do on your categorical data to meaningfully convert it into ordinal or interval? For example, for geographical locations, you can use geolocation and derivatives of it; for words, you can use string similarity metrics; for colors, you can use distance over the palette. These examples are quite random and might not be of any use to you, but working with categorical data is very dependent on the context and the meaning that could be extracted from the categories.

Comment: If you have no way of introducing at least a partial order over your categorical data, your possibilities are very limited. Notice that the article, shared by @Drey talks of converting the data to numbers (ordinal, even interval). Practically, with categorical data, you are limited to having if-x-is-equal-to-y predicates, and no other possible comparisons. As suggest, variations of [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) are probably the only approach that excludes some sort of mapping over numbers. For kNN you again need to map your space to numbers in some way.

Comment: @mapto No, the categorical values are user defined completely unrelated distinct values like **branch_name**, **employee_name**, **product_name**. Where they are all having the scope of either being yes or no.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with such data?

Comment: I use this data to see if there is any pattern in defaulters list.

Comment: One optimisation you could try to do, is to reduce the space of each dimension by collapsing very similar texts, i.e. cater for spelling mistakes. Give it a good thought where it makes sense at all, ideally validating your hypotheses. But in general, I'm still convinced Random Forest or some other variation of Decision Trees is your best bet

Comment: Thanks @mapto. Decision tree sprinkled some light on this! I'm looking at sanitizing the data set now.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

I think the 53 category issue is specific to R's `randomForest` package. If you're set on using a random forest, try other packages like `ranger` and `Rborist`.